# Access an IP whitelist secured API from a kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, whitelist

I am working on an application that will integrate with an external API that performs access restriction via IP whitelisting.

This application is going to be hosted on a Kubernetes cluster (on AWS if that is of any help).

Would there be a way for my application to have a single source IP that I would just register on the 3rd party API?

Technically, I could go ahead and have the API register all the IPs of the worker nodes. But that feels rather clunky and would need to be amended each time the cluster structure changes as new nodes are added, removed, restarted, etc.

I saw some posts about setting up a sort of reverse proxy/request funnel for the application to only come from one source, but this is just essentially defining a single point of failure, which I would really like to avoid.

Comment: if you setup a NAT gateway then API server is going to see IP(s) of NAT gateway and not worker nodes.

Comment: Hi @sameer-naik , thanks for the comment. Would you be able to elaborate somewhat more? Possibly supply reference to guides, etc.

Comment: Please see section "Public endpoint only" from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/de-mystifying-cluster-networking-for-amazon-eks-worker-nodes/ and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-public-private-vpc.html